# create html dom element in front end using node js

Tags: node.js, html

I'm new to node js. Is that possible to create a html dom element on front end(index.html) using node js. If I insert any data into DB means then I want to create an html dom element like "li" (list) to show the inserted data in my index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a html dom element in an existing html document is possible with javascript and whatever is your backend. You just use `document.createElement()` or whith jquery `$('mytag').append('newTag)`. You can send JSON or (XML) from your server: `res.json({foo: 'bar')` with expressjs for example. Then from the client you make an AJAJ (AJAX) call to the route of your backend.  I think what you are trying to do is a Single Page Application.

Comment: Thank you franckstifler.